# The nested for loop stops after 2nd iteration and asks for user input (not used input function in the python code)

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, for-loop, nested

The outer for loop is not interating over the entire sequence 'L1'. The iteration stops after first two values[i.e. after(10,3,3)].

After displaying the output for first two items in L1,the message displayed is'The program is still running' and it asks for an input.(Strangely, I have not used the function input anywhere in the entire code)

The code is -

```
    import random
    import array
    L1 = [(12, 8, 3), (10, 3, 3), (9, 7, 2), (6, 10, 2)]
    
    for val in L1:
        n = val[0]
        k = val[1]
        b = val[2]
        if b >= 1 and b <= (10^5) and n >= 1 and k <= (10^18) and b <= k :
            L5 = list(range(1, k+1))
            A = 0
            for z in L5:
                A = A+z
            print(A)
            while A >= n:
                L3 = []
                for w in range(0, b):
                    p = random.randint(1, k)
                    L3.append(p)
                S3 = set(L3)
                L4 = list(S3)
                if len(L4) != 3:
                    continue
                else:
                    print('I worked for', n, k, b)
                break
            else:
                print('I printed -1 for' ,n,k, b )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get stuck in the `while A >= n` loop. Your `A` is not changing inside that loop and the `continue` inside of `if len(L4) != 3` stops you from reaching the `break`. Therefore the loop becomes infinite.